# Azure Databricks: Switching from batch to streaming mode

Tags: azure, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks, spark-structured-streaming

Hello spark community,

Currently we have a batch pipeline in azure databricks that reads from a delta table. Job is run every night once per day. We extract its data, save it in our own location as delta table again and then we write to azure sql database table. Everything is partioned on date like this: Date=2021-01-01, etc.

Things are about to change now since our source delta table is about to get refreshed every 2-3 minutes and the requirement is to change the ETL from nightly batch to streaming mode but still using the same source and target tables as well as the same sql database table.

Right now this streaming challenge is imposing several questions:

1. Our delta source table is quite huge (30B+ rows), so far in our nightly batch we extracted only the changed date keys and used MERGE INTO to write the updates/inserts, however once we switch to streaming mode is it possible to tell spark to start streaming from a specific point in time since we do not want to load the whole table again this time with streaming mode?
2. How do you write a stream to a target delta table with MERGE INTO having to check huge amount of keys on both sides. I suppose we can get use of a foreachBatch and do that in a micro batch manner, but still how each new micro batch to check for existing/non-existing keys in our target delta table in a time-efficient manner (30B+ rows in the current target table)?
3. Not sure about that but is it possible for a streaming spark job to write directly to a sql database (azure) and will this become a bottleneck situation hence not advisable to be done?

I am really looking forward for some good advice and design decisions since this would be quite a big issue with the current data size. Appreciate every opinion here!